# How to convert English language to French in an application in PHP using Zend framework

Tags: php, language-translation, zend-framework-mvc

I am an application developer. I have recently started learning Zendframework. I have to introduce an option for viewing the web page in French, which means the content has to be translated in French. The same content which appears in English in the web page has to be translated to French. So, what should I do? Please suggest.

Comment: By reading the documentation about [i18n](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html).

Comment: Learn about i18n (internationalisation) and hire a translator (or do the translations by hand yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Why a requirement to use Zend? Remove that from the euqation and...

```
<?php
include('http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/1/file/28706/name/api_googletranslate.class.php');

define('BASE_LANG', 'en');

function getLang()
{
   $langs=array();
   $opts=exlpode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
   foreach ($opts as $accept) {
     $propose=shift(explode('-', $accept));
     if (preg_match('/^([a-z]{2}$/', $propose)) {
        $langs[]=$propose;
     }
   }
   return $langs;
}
$langs=getLang();
if (!count($lang) || in_array($langs, BASE_LANG)) {
    print file_get_contents($contentfile);
    exit;
}
foreach ($langs as $try) {
   if (!file_exists($contentfile . "." . $try)) {
      print file_get_contents($contentfile . "." . $try);
      exit;
}
$translate = new GoogleTranslateApi; 
$translate->FromLang = BASE_LANG; 
$translate->ToLang = $langs[0];
print $translate->translate(file_get_contents($contentfile));
```